# Reading Django Logger data programmatically?

Tags: python, django, logging

I'm using Django for logging bunch of logs. My system is serving millions of requests every minute so I've removed all the logging from my SQL DB to Django loggers to flat files for the sake of latency.

However, since millions of lines are written to log files, I have to write some log reader module to read those logs and present it on dashboard so that I can take a look at them everyday.

So I was curious, is there any module in Django (or some Django snippet) that can read logger logs programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Sentry](http://sentry.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) is probably a direct answer to your question but I would recommend you look into other options for log mining.

Take a look at [Loggly](http://www.loggly.com/) which offers logging as a service and the dashboard comes pre-built. [Orange](http://orange.biolab.si/) has toolkit in python to do this too. [Python, web log data mining for frequent patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925555/python-web-log-data-mining-for-frequent-patterns) might be of some help.